# LWC Component how to use only custom fields

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

[image]how to fetch only custom fields in this code
I have created a LW component for getting object information when I enter the object name in the search I get all fields in that object but I need only custom fields to be listed when I enter the object name.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import {getObjectInfo} from 
export default class WireGetObjectInfo extends LightningElement {
    objectApiNameInputValue = 'Account';
    objectApiName;
    @track objectInfo;
    fieldApiNameInputValue;
    fieldApiName;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })
    objectInfo;
    objectNameChange(event) {
        this.objectApiNameInputValue = event.target.value;
    }
    handleBtnClick() {
        this.objectApiName = this.objectApiNameInputValue;
    }
    fieldNameChange(event) {
        this.fieldApiNameInputValue = event.target.value;
    }
    get fieldOptions() {
        let fieldList = [];
        if (this.objectInfo) {
            if (this.objectInfo.data) {
                if (this.objectInfo.data.fields) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.fields).length; i++) {
                        fieldList.push({
                            label: Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.fields)[i][0],
                            value: Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.fields)[i][0]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fieldList;
    }
    

}
```

JS FILE

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Get Object Information " icon-name="custom:custom67">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="12" large-device-size="12"
                padding="around-small">
                <div class="slds-m-horizontal_medium">
                    <lightning-input value={objectApiNameInputValue} placeholder="Enter object API name"
                        onchange={objectNameChange} label="Search"></lightning-input>
                    <p class="slds-p-vertical_small">
                        <lightning-button label="Get Object Info" onclick={handleBtnClick}></lightning-button>
                    </p>
                    <template if:true={objectInfo.data}>
                        <lightning-combobox name="fieldApiName" label="Select Field To Get Informtion" value=""
                            placeholder="Select Field Api Name" options={fieldOptions} onchange={fieldNameChange}
                            required>
                        </lightning-combobox>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

HTML FILE

public with sharing class dynamicObjectList {

```
private static String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() 
+ '/services/data/v46.0/tooling/query?q=Select+MetadataComponentId,MetadataComponentName,RefMetadataComponentName,RefMetadataComponentId,MetadataComponentType+from+MetadataComponentDependency+where+MetadataComponentId=\'00NIw0000011xDN\'';

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
```

public static string getfields(string objectname, string fieldApiName){
string query = 'select DeveloperName,QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinitionId = :objectname and QualifiedApiName =:fieldApiName ORDER BY DeveloperName ASC';
list lstObject = Database.query(query);
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
req.setEndpoint(baseUrl);
req.setMethod('GET');
// OAuth header
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

```
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
   return res.getBody();
```

}
}

Apex class

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the custom fields, you can filter for that:

```
get fieldOptions() {
  if(this.objectInfo.data) {
    return Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.fields)
      .filter(([_,{custom}])=>custom)
      .map(([value,{label}])=>({value,label}));
  }
  return [];
}
```

Note a lot of optimizations here:

```
if(this.objectInfo.data) {
```

Up to this point will always be safe to check in a wire-bound property, as these are initialized before your first getter is ever called.

```
    return Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.fields)
```

Converts the fields of an object into an array.

```
      .filter(([_,{custom}])=>custom)
```

Takes the field describe info from the second index (array index 1), pulls out the `custom` property, and then returns only those entries that are custom fields.

```
      .map(([value,{label}])=>({value,label}));
```

Converts the filtered array into a label-value pair.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox I got custom fields how do know where the custom fields are used in the same code how do I write code to know where the fields are used

Comment: @shaktivel What do you mean "where the fields are used"? Like a metadata dependency report? It sounds like you want the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) object.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox yes I need to know custom fields where and all they are used like where they are used in VF pages, Components, Apex, Reports, Flows, pages and all other places where ever the field is used like MetadataComponentDependency but in a component I have written code to write the object name and then the custom fields appear in a picklist and then when I select the field i need to where and all they are used in the org. thanks

Comment: hi @sfdcfox I am trying with this apex class

Comment: pretty cool utilization of destructuring)